# Generate random number of missing values in R

Tags: r, random

I have a data frame such like that:

```
df<-data.frame(time1=rbinom(100,1,0.3),
               time2=rbinom(100,1,0.4),
               time3=rbinom(100,1,0.5),
               time4=rbinom(100,1,0.6))
```

How could I generate random missing values for each time variable with up to 20% number of missing? Namely, in this case, the total number of missing less than 20 in each column and they are missed in random from subjects (rows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do:

```
insert_nas <- function(x) {
  len <- length(x)
  n <- sample(1:floor(0.2*len), 1)
  i <- sample(1:len, n)
  x[i] <- NA 
  x
}

df2 <- sapply(df, insert_nas)
df2
```

This will give you up to maximal 20% missings per column

```
colSums(is.na(df2)) / nrow(df2)

time1 time2 time3 time4 
 0.09  0.16  0.19  0.14
```

Comment: I'd prefer `n <- sample.int(floor(0.2*len), 1); i <- sample(seq_along(x), n)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) 
               "is.na<-"(x, sample(seq(x), floor(length(x) * runif(1, 0, .2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you mean?

```
nomissing <- sample(1:20,1)
testnos <- rbinom(100 - nomissing,1,0.3)
testnas <- rep(NA,nomissing)
testmix <- sample(x = c(testnos,testnas),100)
```

Output -

```
> testmix
  [1]  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
 [37]  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1 NA  0  1  0  0
 [73]  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 NA NA  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: The number of missing **up to 20**, which means each variable may have any number of missing values range from 1-20. and the number of rows are still 100.